# How to Use LINQ to query to extract Subqueries

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to write a code inside of the main class below. What I need is:
string format.

```
     class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
            List<Person> human = new List<Person>()
            {
              new Person("Sarah", 18), new Person("Peter", 33),
              new Person("Paul", 29), new Child("Kevin", 15, true), new Child("Maria", 9, false)
            };
 
          
        }
//
        class Person
        {
            public string Firstname { get; set; }
            public int Age { get; set; }

            public Person(string fn, int ag)
            {
                this.Firstname = fn;
                this.Age = ag;
            }

        }
//
        class Child : Person   
        {
            public bool IsMale { get; set; }

            public Child(string fn, int ag, bool isM) : base(fn, ag) 
            {
                this.IsMale = isM;
            }

        }
////new feature:
public virtual string CalMe()
{
return "Hiii";
}
    }
```

Could you please correct my answer in the comment or write a new answer there?
Thanks

Comment: Please avoid editing questions so drastically that it invalidates existing answers.

Comment: `class, List<Car>, new`  is not valid C.  For questions tagged C, best to post C code that compiles.

Comment: You keep changing your question. That's *very* frustrating for people trying to answer it. Moreover, in its current form its totally unclear what you want, what you tried, and how you would need this "string format".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [OfType()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.oftype?view=net-6.0) construction to filter out all `Child`ren from `Person`s:

```
var femaleChildren = human
  .OfType<Child>()                // children only
  .Where(child => !child.IsMale); // which are not male

foreach (var child in femaleChildren)
  Console.WriteLine($"{child.Firstname} {child.Age}");
```

**Edit:** If you don't want to use `OfType`, you can put `Select` and `Where`:

```
var femaleChildren = human
  .Select(item => item as Child)  // either Child or null
  .Where(item => item != null)    // children only, no nulls 
  .Where(child => !child.IsMale); // which are not male
```

Comment: @arash6657: I'm sorry for the typo, it should be `Firstname`. I've edited the answer

Comment: @arash6657: It prints each `child` - `Console.WriteLine($"{child.Firstname} {child.Age}");` in `Firstname Age` format, e.g. `Maria 9`

Comment: @arash6657: if you don't want use `OfType<T>` you can try either `as` or `is` within `Where` to filter out `Child`ren. Please, see my edit 
`

Answer (score 2):

I don't disagree with Dmitry's answer, but I think combining the checks into a single where probably makes the code read more fluidly

```
human.Where(h => h is Child c && !c.IsMale)
```

As to why your attempt didn't work; not every element in the list is a Child (a Child is a Person but not necessarily the other way round) - they are all capable of behaving like a Person but to be a Child requires a cast before you can access properties that are only available on a Child

---

You've massively edited your question and not given any indication what the new criteria are. The pattern remains the same:

```
cars.Where(c => c is SubCar sc && sc.SomeSubCarOnlyProperty == someValue
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation :)
can you please also write how can I extract via LINQ to query the list for people under the age of 18 with "ALL properties"?
What i wrote was this but I don't know how to include all properties:

           IEnumerable<Person> FilterOurQuery = human.Where(p => p.Age <= 18);
            foreach (Person p in FilterOurQuery)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} {1} ", p.Firstname, p.Age));
            }

Comment: Just extend that string to put more properties in it

Comment: I tried but it showed me just firstname and Age and doesn't show other possibilities

Comment: Your Person class as posted (in the question) does only have 2 properties - I assumed it was a cut down version of your real clsss which has more. Add more properties to Person class and then you will be able to write them into the output string

Comment: Remember too that your filtered list (if you've done `Where(p=>p is Child ...)` ) is full of things that are actually Child type objects so you could cast them to Child and access the IsMale:`foreach(var c in xxx) Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2}", p.Firstname, p.Age, (p as Child).IsMale);`.. You can't safely do this with your p.Age<= 18 though because your <=28 will bring Sarah in too and she is a Person, not a Child

Comment: Typo correction in the above comment: You can't safely do this with your `p.Age<= 18` though because your `<=28` will bring Sarah in too and she is a Person, not a Child

Comment: Thanks but how can i bring only  persons under specific age and not Child?

Comment: `!(p is Child) && p.Age < whatever`

Comment: Dear Caius, I added a virtual string "CallMe" at the end of the code. May I ask, how can I Call "CallMe" for those persons (who we found in the previous step) and return its value?

Comment: If call me accepts a Person then `.Select(CallMe)`, if it accepts something else then eg `.Select(p => CallMe(p.Something))`

Comment: CallMe has only the string value of "Hiii"

Comment: Again, you're editing your question in a way that is approaching ruining the posted answers. Please ask a new question. StackOverflow is like "a wiki of every problem and its answer"; it is not some kind of support ticketing system where you ask once about one thing and then repeatedly edit your question/requirements/process as you work through writing an entire application